# Angular 8 - Get value of checkbox and sent it like a parameter in a function

Tags: angular

Im very new in Angular and i got a question.
I want to send the value of the checkbox in a parameter of a function like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="updateRol(rol.id, VALUE-OF-CHECKBOX-HERE)" />{{rol.id}}
```

How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a local template reference variable for this:

```
<input #rolInput type="checkbox" (click)="updateRol(rol.id, rolInput.checked)" />{{rol.id}}
```

See https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var

Answer (score 0):

Bind ngModel to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkbox" (click)="updateRol(rol.id)" />
```

Create member inside the component:

```
checkbox: boolean;
```

Use/access the "checkbox" variable inside you component's function of `updateRol(id)` as `this.checkbox`

Comment: I test with that:
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="rolesAssignated[rol.id]>0" 
    ng-init="checkbox: boolean;"
    [(ngModel)]="checkbox"
    (click)="updateRol(rol.id, this.checkbox)" />{{rol.id}}

But hive me the follow error:
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("><input type="checkbox" [checked]="rolesAssignated[rol.id]>0" 
    ng-init="checkbox: boolean;"
    [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="checkbox"
    (click)="updateRol(rol.id, this.checkbox)" />{{rol.id}} - {{rol.nombre}}</")

Comment: Import FormsModule in your module, where your component lives.

Comment: But i got a few of <input>, i got the follow code:
<ul *ngFor='let rol of roles'>
  <li><input type="checkbox" [checked]="rolesAssignated[rol.id]>0" 
    ng-init="checkbox: boolean;"
    [(ngModel)]="checkbox"
    (click)="updateRol(rol.id, this.checkbox)" />{{rol.id}}</li>
</ul>

That works on for only one <input>, how i adapted that?